# How to plot two graphs in a single dot file

Tags: graphviz

```
digraph G {
rankdir = "TB";
node [shape=rectangle];

subgraph G1 {
rankdir = "LR";
  A->B
  A->C
}
subgraph G2 {
rankdir = "TB";
  1->2
  1->3
}

}
```

I understand `rankdir` does not work inside the subgraph, and it's a long pending issue.

However, is there any workaround to achieve this?

I also tried `subgraph cluster_*`, but was not able to align two subgraphs in vertically.

[image]

Comment: Is your goal two graphs in a single file or two graphs/subgraphs, with different rankdir values?  Does the image display your goal or your current best effort?

Comment: @sroush Actually, both are the goals. The priority of getting two graphs in a single file is slightly higher though. The MWE does not represent the given Fig. Fig represents what I actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no, or at least not in one step.
A bit more work: yes, like so:

```
digraph G1 {
rankdir = "LR";
node [shape=rectangle];
  A->B
  A->C
}
  ////////////////////////
  // second distinct graph, all one input file
  ////////////////////////
digraph G2 {
rankdir = "TB";
node [shape=rectangle];
  1->2
  1->3
}
```

But the above will only produce one (or zero) graphs if you try to produce png, svg, or the like.
However, this set of commands produces the desired output, using Graphviz tools:

```
dot -Tdot myfile.gv >myfile.dot             ## note: -Tdot
gvpack -array_i1 myfile.dot >packed.dot     ## gvpack is a Graphviz program documented here:  https://graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf
neato -n2 -Tpng packed.dot >packed.png      ## neato -n2 documented here:  https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords
```

Giving:
[image]